Using TipTap version 2, how can I tell if a whole paragraph is selected rather than just some of the text within the paragraph?
I'm experimenting with TipTap v2 and am trying to show a BubbleMenu when the user selects some text.  I'd like to mimic the way the Medium editor works, in that when the user selects a whole paragraph the bubble menu shows options for setting/unsetting headers, but if they select just some of the text then the menu shows text style formatting such as bold, italic, etc.
What I can't work out is how to tell if the user has selected a paragraph or just some text?
I've written a simple function that checks if the user has selected some text.  This works:
const isTextSelection = (editor: Editor) => {
  if (!editor) return false
  const { state } = editor
  const { from, to } = state.selection
   return from !== to
}

but trying to check if the selected text is a paragraph isn't working
const isParagraphSelected = (editor: Editor) => {
  if (!editor) return false
  const { state } = editor
  const { from, to } = state.selection
  const node = state.doc.nodeAt(from)
  return node?.type.name === 'paragraph' && from !== to
}

What is the recommended way to tell if the user has selected a paragraph?

Helo, you can, I haven't tried, to check if "from" = 1 and "to" is equal to the length of range
-> state.selection.from === 1 &&
-> state.selection.to - 1 === state.selection.$head.parent.content.size
